# Swift, Set extension error: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation?

Tags: ios, swift, set

In Swift, I would like to make an extension on Set that takes two arrays, and the function needs to add the elements from one array and remove elements found in another array to the called upon Set.

```
extension Set {
    
    mutating func update<T>(adding a:[T], removing b:[T]) where T:Hashable {
        var r = union(Set<T>(a)) // ERROR: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation
        r.subtract(Set<T>(b))
        self = r
    }
    
}
```

I currently get this error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation`.

How can I fix this so that the Set instance I call this on will update accordingly?

Comment: BTW You can mutate sets in-place with `formIntersection`. So you just need `formIntersection(Set(A)); substract(Set(B))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining your own generic `T`, you should use `Element`, which is already defined on `Set`:

```
extension Set {
    mutating func update(adding a:[Element], removing b:[Element]) {
        var r = union(Set<Element>(a))
        r.subtract(Set<Element>(b))
        self = r
    }
}
```

Comment: And in this context, `Set` is inferred to be `Set<Element>`, so you can omit the explicit generic parameter

Comment: True -- the type annotation is optional